# Anaconda "trial mode expires in x days" error message

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

I have just installed anaconda on my Mac and any time I execute a *conda* command or start a *python* instance I get the following odd error message:

```
ianashpole $ conda info --envs
Vendor:  continuum
Product: anaconda
Message: trial mode expires in 27 days
```

OR

```
ianashpole $ python
Vendor:  continuum
Product: anaconda
Message: trial mode expires in 27 days
Python 2.7.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2012,09:57:39)
```

To clarify, I haven't installed any additional packages or anything after the initial download from https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos

Does anybody know a) how to stop this message from appearing; and b) whether anaconda really will stop working for me in 27 days?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered this myself - a simple uninstall and reinstall seems to have done the trick!